# Android request permission on startup

Tags: android, permissions

I have an old app running fine before but with the new update. It needs now a request permission. I'm able to show the permission. But the problem is that, the "TestNavigationDrawer has stopped" also appears in the startup along with the PERMISSION REQUESTS. I'm not sure where to put the request permission or if I put the right one. Please help me with this. Thank you in advance. I also provided some screenshots to clarify this (the "TestNavigationDrawer has stopped" also appears in the startup along with the PERMISSION REQUESTS.)

[Click here to see the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bayzi.png)

This is my code. I even put the permission request at the top most of the onCreate to avoid the error.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if(checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == 
PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        System.out.println("Permission Granted");
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 10, this);
    } else{
        String[] permissionRequested={Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION};
        requestPermissions(permissionRequested, ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   /* HomeFragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();*/

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);



    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

     navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

}
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "PERMISSION NOT GRANTED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: move if else code after  avigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

Comment: Hello @DivyeshPatel. First of all, thank you for responding on my post. I just tried your suggested solution but it still didn't work. Also, the app has stopped first before showing the permissions. It's still the same error in my error log. Here it is.

"gps" location provider requires ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you need to call all the stuff below permission request, (LocationManager) etc .. when the permission is granted .. 
Put all the code in a separate function and call that function in onRequestPermissionResult ..

Comment: This is working. I have updated now my code. Thank you so much for the idea. Although if you have time, you can add more specific instructions on how to do it for some developers too. But i've managed to understand what you are trying to make me do. Thanks, Umer!

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with below

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if(checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
    System.out.println("Permission Granted");


    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 10, this);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
        this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    } else{
        String[] permissionRequested={Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION};
        requestPermissions(permissionRequested, ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

}
```

Because if you keep location manager code out side if conditional statement that means permission if permission is not given and you are still accessing location that's cause crashing . Use location after permission is given that is your code should pass if statement
Hope that helps

Comment: Hello, Abdul. Thank you for your respond. I have solved it now with the help of  Umer. Your approach too is the same as him but I think we shouldnt add the drawer layout inside the if statement. it is throwing another error if we did that. Thanks though :)